# Magento shopping cart gives out of memory error

Tags: magento

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/ssmagnet/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php  on line 103

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: This isn't really a programing question, furthermore you spelled "Magento" wrong in the title.

Comment: Also check for multiple `memory_limit` settings via layers of ini files. My nginx install had a `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/default.ini` with memory_limit=32M which was giving me problems.

Answer (score -1):

Your memory limit is too low. Check your .htaccess file in the Magento directory and change the value of `php_value memory_limit` to bump it up a bit. If you don't see a line like this, add it to the bottom of the file. A value that's worked for me is:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: did that but not working yet 
http://www.ssbikinishop.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

Comment: Did you make sure to restart apache so that it would read the new value? What  is the value at?

Comment: i tried it on the server and the value i tried with is 128M 256M

Comment: If that is the case, you should have plenty of memory for most tasks. Try disabling all of your extensions (via their modules xml files, not the admin panel) and see if the issue goes away.